# The replaceAll() with regular expression not working

Tags: java, regex

This is my Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = in.nextLine();

String pattern = "^co[a-z|A-Z]e$";

String b = a.replaceAll(pattern,"1");
System.out.print(b);
```

I just had to replace the word "code" or any word with "co'[a-z|A-Z]'e" with '1', but it seems to work only when the input string is "code" and nothing else

*Example Input*:  `codexxccope`

*Expected Output*: `1xxc1`

*My Output*: `codexxccope`

*Example Input 2*: `code`

*My Output*: `1`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `String pattern = "\\bco[a-zA-Z]e\\b";`

Comment: `^` stands for string start and `$` for string end. Which means that the pattern will be replaced only when the entire string matches it.

Comment: Also, inside a character class the `|` symbol is an ordinary character.  If you want to match only upper- and lowercase Latin letters, then just remove it from the character class altogether.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it's still not working, giving the same output

Comment: Sorry, just remove the anchors, use `String pattern = "co[a-zA-Z]e";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here: `^` matches the start of string position, `$` matches the end of string position, and `[a-z|A-Z]` matches any ASCII letter or `|` (as the pipe inside the character class matches the literal `|` char.

Use

```
String pattern = "co[a-zA-Z]e";
```

The `[a-zA-Z]` character class matches any ASCII letter.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Y9LuK/1).